# How can I prevent Windows10 from sending a TCP RST to a particular IP nad PORT?

Tags: tcp, tcp-rst

I have been analyzing packets sent out from my IP to a game server.
The connection to the server was getting reset for some reason and after packet capture, I could see that there are TCP RST packets sent at the time of the disconnection.
I have tried to use advance firewall to specifically only restrict the TCP RST packets to the game server to see if that will prevent this disconnection. However I am unable to specify the flag level details in the rules.
How can I accomplish this configuration?
Is there any third party firewall that can do this?

Thank you

Comment: The TCP RST is likely the result of the disconnect and not the cause of it. By focusing on the RST instead of the original cause you basically try to take over the control of a crashed car after the accident already happened - i.e. it will not help.

Comment: Also, after the TCP RST was send or even before  there is/was no longer a matching connection on your client. This means even if the RST would be successfully blocked the connection would still be killed.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I had realized that blocking RST would not be ideal. However I still wish to find out if there is something similar to iptables in windows 10.